# How do you check glue records if your ISP blocks access to the root servers?

Tags: dns

Glue servers, apparently appear in the parent of the domain. How can these be queried, when for the last few months ISPs have been blocking access to the nameserver ports due to DoS attacks with spoofed UDP packets? Or is this no longer possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about applications and application-layer protocols are off-topic here, as are questions about bypassing network security. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: You need to have this conversation with your moronic ISP. You address spoofing by *preventing spoofing*. Screwing with DNS is not that.

Answer (score 3):

Change your ISP. Blocking access to root DNS servers with "DoS prevention" is not something a serious ISP would practice (unless you live in a country with government regulations in place).

Alternatively, [use a web service.](https://mebsd.com/glue)